# Start timer at the same time on every client

Tags: networking, client-server, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a multiplayer game in Unity3D and I'd like some help with synchronization. One of the players act as a server and everybody else are clients. At some point in the game, all players have 10 seconds to answer a question before they move on to the next step of the game. The time it takes them to answer the question is recorded and used to figure out the fastest answer, so it is very critical that all clients start their timers at the same time.

What is the best way to structure this as far as messaging goes? And what information will these messages contain?

Things I've tried/thought:

- The server starts the timer and tells everybody to do the same. Problem: if any client is lagging, the question pops up at different times.
- The server starts the timer and tells everybody the DateTime the timer started. Problem: if a client is lagging, he'll jump immediately to a specific time instead of the beginning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the server give the signal to start the timer, along with a DateTime. Instead of starting the timer at the same time as the message, give the clients a DateTime occurring a few seconds after the message is sent. That way the clients won't start the timer as soon as they get the message, allowing for those with lag to 'catch up.'
(e.g. The signal is sent at 7:00:00 AM, containing the time 7:00:05. As the clients recieve the message, they wait to start the timer until 7:00:05, so all the timers can start at the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who you're developing the game for, you could always just let the clients handle the timing. Have the server give the signal for the clients to display the question and start the timer, and then wait for the responses. Each client can then time the user and give the time to the server along with the user's answer. As long as the server gives the clients a 'buffer' of a couple seconds, it should recieve all the answers with accurate timing, no matter how much lag there is.

The only problem with this is that, again depending on your audience, users could potentially tamper with the sent data.

Comment: I'm OK with the tampering for now, since this is more of a proof of concept. However, this also has the same problem as my first solution, namely, that depending on their lag, they will start their timers in different times because the signal from the server comes in late.

Comment: @pek If there is lag and a particular user is given the question later than other users, as long as the client's timer is used to record the start and finish time the amount of time between the appearance of the question and the answer should be accurate.I guess what I'm saying is that if it's OK for the answers to be timed relative to the clients, this should work-even with lag.

Comment: @pek The clients would return their completion time to the server, relative to their own starting time.  The server just has to wait for all N responses to come in before declaring a winner.  If timing happens on the client side, the only issue you need to handle is what happens if a user disconnects before answering.

Comment: I see. I can definitely do that, but am I asking too much if I wanted them to start at the same time? That's mainly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @pek You could have the server give the signal to start the timer, along with a DateTime. Instead of starting the timer at the same time as the message, give the clients a DateTime occurring a few seconds after the message is sent. That way the clients won't start the timer as soon as they get the message, allowing for those with lag to 'catch up.' (e.g. The signal is sent at 7:00:00 AM, containing the time 7:00:05. As the clients recieve the message, they wait to start the timer until 7:00:05, so all the timers can start at the same time.)

Comment: Can you make this into a separate answer so people can vote? Also, this is closer to what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! Sorry about taking so long-I thought I had posted it. Apparently my computer didn't take it well.